# AKS start/stop cluster in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-aks, azure-cli, azure-automation

Is it possible to run this two commands as a PowerShell cmdlet?

az aks stop --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup

az aks start --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup

I cannot find the PowerShell equivalent here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.aks/?view=azps-6.2.1

The reason why I'm asking this:

- I would like to run those commands within an Azure Automation runbook, so therefore I need the PowerShell cmdlets. Or is there any other way to run azure cli from a runbook?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell cmdlet you can run in [Azure Automation runbook to start /stop AKS cluster](https://github.com/LATAMOCPTECHTEAM/aks-start-stop-automation) here.

> az aks stop --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup
>
> az aks start --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup

You Can use this above command in  Azure CLI to [stop and start a Kubernetes Service Cluster](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip308.html).

To Start and Stop AKS Cluster using  [Powershell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/Aks/Aks/help/Az.Aks.md)  You need to use below example code:

```
Start-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName group -Name myCluster
Stop-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName group -Name myCluster
```

For further details please refer this [Link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/start-stop-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

Usually if we use PowerShell then Automation runbook can work for us. Unfortunately I could not find PowerShell to start/ stop AKS. I found this marketplace solution that runs a VM and shuts down/ starts AKS cluster on the time specified. Refer this link for the deployment -
https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/apps/bowspritconsultingopcprivatelimited1596291408582.aksautomation2?tab=Overview